# Ranking of data using MatLab

Tags: matlab, spreadsheet, ranking

I am working on a project to rank bollywood stars according to their popularity.

I've gathered info about them, for e.g no of movies, no of hits in google, no of facebook fans, estimated worth, etc, in a spreadsheet.

Now I want to know how I can use Matlab to rank them in ascending order of popularity based on those attributes I collected.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use sortrows.

Import the spread sheet data into MATLAB and ensure the data is an array.

```
mydata = xlsread(filename)
```

Then sort the rows of mydata.

```
cs = sortrows(mydata,[1,2])
```

%# sort the first col ascending, then second ascending. If you want to order it descending,put a negative sign like this:

```
cs = sortrows(mydata,[-1, -2])
```